# How to make a checkbox automatically checked by value C#?

Tags: c#

How to make a checkbox automatically checked by value? Example if the value = 1, checkbox automatically checked and if the value = 0 checkbox isn't checked. I used "RepositoryItemCheckEdit" for the checkbox in gridView, please help me...

I try this code and it can't automatically checked

```
        GridColumn fCol = gridView1.Columns.Add();
        RepositoryItemCheckEdit Check = new RepositoryItemCheckEdit();
        Check.ValueChecked = Convert.ToInt16 ("1");
        Check.ValueUnchecked = Convert.ToInt16 ("0");
        fCol.ColumnEdit = Check;
        fCol.FieldName = "Is_Kit";
```

Comment: I'm not sure I really understand the question...

Comment: Key word data binding.

Comment: I believe the poster has an item of type `DevExpress.XtraEditors.Repository.RepositoryItemCheckEdit` and he wants to set whether or not it is checked or not (I assume this renders as a checkbox type control though it is unclear from the docs).

Comment: I think my code is wrong, can u help me to write the right code for checkbox automatically checked if the value = 0???

Comment: Do you intend to use CheckEdit instead of RepositoryItemCheckEdit. CheckEdit is the actual control which will be rendered.